# ApexCharts - Adding a number inside the "Simple Donut Chart"

Tags: javascript, html, apexcharts

I have been trying to add a number on the inside of the "Simple donut chart" from ApexCharts. This is the link to it - https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/pie-charts/simple-donut/ .

To use the chart, I ran the command "npm install apexcharts --save" in my project terminal.

This is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Chart.css">

    <script src="./Chart.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

</head>

<div id="chart"></div>
    <script>
        const chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();
    </script>

</html>
```

This is my CSS file:

```
#chart{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This is what I used in my JavaScript file:

```
var options = {
    series: [44, 55, 41, 60],
    labels: ["Transport", "Shopping", "Energy use", "Food"],
    chart: {
        type: 'donut',
    },
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 480,
        options: {
            chart: {
                width: 200
            },
            legend: {
                position: 'bottom'
            }
        }
    }]
};
```

This is the result of the code mentioned above:

[Current Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt2Lp.png)

This is a model to show how I would like the number to be displayed:

[Example Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAm6W.png)

I would like to know if its possible to add a number inside the current chart with ApexCharts as the example chart shows.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider posting your implementation code so that other people can have a starting point to better help you.

Answer (score 9):

Yes it's possible.

```js
let options = {
  series: [44, 55, 41, 60],
  labels: ["Transport", "Shopping", "Energy use", "Food"],
  chart: {
    type: 'donut',
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      donut: {
        labels: {
          show: true,
          total: {
            show: true,
            label: '',
            formatter: () => 'Text you want'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

const chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@3.18.1/dist/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

You can show the following information inside a donut:

- a value of an individual donut piece (on hover to that piece)
- the total of all the donut pieces
- custom text

Try to change values of the `total` object properties to better understanding what I mean. More detailed information is [here](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/pie/)